# Spinner is not quite displaying correct number if spinner is blank

Tags: javascript, function, spinner

I have 5 spinners which are almost working perfectly, there is just one little glitch I cannot overcome.

What is suppose to happen is that if a spinner is blank, whatever the previous number was in THAT spinner, it will display that previous number.

Instead what it is doing is that any previous number that has been entered in ANY of the 5 spinners, it displays that number in the blank spinner.

So how can I get it so that it displays the previous number from that spinner if a spinner is blank rather than displaying the last previous number entered from any spinner in the blank spinner?

Below is my spinner code:

```
     function Spinner(elem,min, max){
 this.elem = elem;
 this.elem.value = min;
 this.min = min;
 this.max = max;
 this.timer;
 this.speed = 150; //milliseconds between scroll values
 var selfO = this;

 this.elem.onkeyup = function(){
    var regex = /^[0-9]*$/;
    if(!regex.test(selfO.elem.value)){
    selfO.elem.value = selfO.elem.value.substring(0,selfO.elem.value.length-1);
                            return;
                        }
                        selfO.validateValue();
                    }

      this.validateValue = function(){
      if(Number(selfO.elem.value) > selfO.max) {selfO.elem.value = selfO.max;}
      if(Number(selfO.elem.value) < selfO.min) {selfO.elem.value = selfO.min;}
                    }

                    this.stopSpinning = function(){
                        clearTimeout(selfO.timer);
                    }

                    this.spinValue = function(dir){
                        selfO.elem.value = Number(selfO.elem.value) + dir;
                        selfO.validateValue();
                        selfO.timer = setTimeout(function(){selfO.spinValue(dir);},selfO.speed);
                    }

                };

           window.onload=function(){
                        //create the Spinner objects
                        var SpinnerHours = new Spinner(document.getElementById('txtHours'),0,23);                
                        var SpinnerMins = new Spinner(document.getElementById('txtMins'),0,59);
                        var SpinnerSecs = new Spinner(document.getElementById('txtSecs'),0,59);
                        var SpinnerWeight = new Spinner(document.getElementById('txtWeight'),0,100);
                        var SpinnerQuestion = new Spinner(document.getElementById('txtQuestion'),0,100);

                        document.getElementById('txtHours').onblur = function(){ this.value = cleanSpin(this.value);}
                        document.getElementById('txtMins').onblur = function(){ this.value = cleanSpin(this.value);}
                        document.getElementById('txtSecs').onblur = function(){ this.value = cleanSpin(this.value);}
                        document.getElementById('txtWeight').onblur = function(){ this.value = cleanSpin(this.value);}
                        document.getElementById('txtQuestion').onblur = function(){ this.value = cleanSpin(this.value);}

            function cleanSpin(obj) {
                if(obj > 0) {
                    var str = obj.replace(/^0*/,'');
                    lastSpin = str;
                    return str;
                }
                else {
                    return lastSpin;
                }
            }

            var lastSpin = 1;
```

Comment: Where is the Spinner class coming from? It is not standard Javascript AFAIK.

Comment: I am going to guess that it comes from jQuery UI, but I am curious what this line does. cleanSpin(this.value);

Comment: I didn't want to overload with code but if you want the spinner class then I have now included this in the question with the validation of the value. I think the problem though is in my cleanSpin() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `lastSpin` variable, and indeed, your `cleanSpin()` function, are in the global scope, and thus shared across all Spinner instances.

Instead, you should try adding the `cleanSpin` method, or a variant thereof, to the `Spinner` "class", so that it becomes local to that instance of the Spinner.

**EDIT:** Here is the complete Javascript to illustrate what I meant. I have not tested this at all, as I do not have the rest of the code needed to do so, but hopefully you can see what I have changed:

```
function Spinner(elem, min, max) {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.elem.value = min;
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.timer;
    this.speed = 150; //milliseconds between scroll values
    this.lastSpin = 1; // added lastSpin as a property of the Spinner
    var selfO = this;

    this.elem.onkeyup = function() {
        var regex = /^[0-9]*$/;
        if (!regex.test(selfO.elem.value)) {
            selfO.elem.value = selfO.elem.value.substring(0, selfO.elem.value.length - 1);
            return;
        }
        selfO.validateValue();
    }

    // I have added the onblur function inside the Spinner "class"
    this.elem.onblur = function() {
        if (self0.elem.value > 0) {
            var str = self0.elem.value.replace(/^0*/, '');
            self0.lastSpin = str;
            self0.elem.value = str;
        }
        else {
            self0.elem.value = lastSpin;
        }
    };

    this.validateValue = function() {
        if (Number(selfO.elem.value) > selfO.max) {
            selfO.elem.value = selfO.max;
        }
        if (Number(selfO.elem.value) < selfO.min) {
            selfO.elem.value = selfO.min;
        }
    };

    this.stopSpinning = function() {
        clearTimeout(selfO.timer);
    };

    this.spinValue = function(dir) {
        selfO.elem.value = Number(selfO.elem.value) + dir;
        selfO.validateValue();
        selfO.timer = setTimeout(function() {
            selfO.spinValue(dir);
        }, selfO.speed);
    };

};

window.onload = function() {
    //create the Spinner objects
    var SpinnerHours = new Spinner(document.getElementById('txtHours'), 0, 23);
    var SpinnerMins = new Spinner(document.getElementById('txtMins'), 0, 59);
    var SpinnerSecs = new Spinner(document.getElementById('txtSecs'), 0, 59);
    var SpinnerWeight = new Spinner(document.getElementById('txtWeight'), 0, 100);
    var SpinnerQuestion = new Spinner(document.getElementById('txtQuestion'), 0, 100);
}
```

Comment: I editted your answer, Is this what you meant for example:                                                              <td class="spinner"><textarea class="spinner" name="txtHours" id="txtHours" cols="2" rows="1" onblur="cleanSpin(obj)"></textarea></td>                                                              <td class="spinner"><textarea class="spinner" name="txtMins" id="txtMins" cols="2" rows="1" onblur="cleanSpin(obj)"></textarea></td>

Comment: I can see what you mean. this code does remove all zeros in front of a number in the spinner which did work before but strangly enough if a spinner is blank and I click away, it doesn't display anything in the spinner. I will check this out. If you look at this again can you please look at your code and see why, I will look at my document and see if I can figure it out :)

Comment: I think its the this.lastSpin = 1 which is the fault but I am still trying to figure it out